# Discord.py await bot.wait_for waits for one message only, instead of two or more

Tags: python, discord.py

I made blackjack game for my discord bot and made a system that adds one card if you write in chat 'hit' or stand if you write 'stand'. It works, but you can hit or stand only one time (you can write hit and if you want to write hit adain or stand the process just gonna stop)

```
    def check(msg):
    if msg.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        return msg
mes = await bot.wait_for('message', check= check)
if (mes.content.startswith('h')) or (mes.content.startswith('H')):
   #my code here
if (mes.content.startswith('s')) or (mes.content.startswith('S')):
   #my code here
```

Comment: You could use a while loop? End it when the user inputs `exit` or something similar?

Comment: why would it wait for more than one message? you're explicitly waiting only *once*.

Comment: Lukasz, how do I make bot wait more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to loop two times and if you need to loop infinite you can use `while(True)` to loop multiple times. Like in the below code

```py
def check(msg):
    if msg.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        return msg
for i in range(2):
  mes = await bot.wait_for('message',timeout=60.0, check= check)
  if (mes.content.startswith('h')) or (mes.content.startswith('H')):
    #my code here
  if (mes.content.startswith('s')) or (mes.content.startswith('S')):
    #my code here
```